# Using Angular2 from a script inside an iframe of the main document

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, angular2-directives

Note: I am new to Angular, any version.

I am trying to add some Angular2 parts to the web UI that is otherwise implemented using other frameworks. In the scenario I have (and cannot get away from) the main document does not have (much) JavaScript running in it at all - all scripts are inside iframe element(s) inside that document, as managed by the main framework.

I didn't even try to load Angular2 in that iframe, assuming that would not work. When it is needed (rarely), I "eval" all required Angular scripts on the main/root window to introduce Angular to it (once), but I have to have the JavaScript code configuring it inside the iframe, at least a bit of it and, because of that, it would be simpler for me to put all of it there. Inside that iframe I declared "ng" to be the "ng" from the main window. That enabled me to run the Angular2 5 minute quick start and worked fine. However, when I started adding more content via directives (I followed http://www.gurustop.net/blog/2015/12/16/angular2-beta-javascript-component) this didn't work. Specifically, it threw exceptions from this Angular2 function:

TypeScript:

```
function isValidType(value: Type): boolean {
  return isPresent(value) && (value instanceof Type);
}
```

Actual JavaScript:

```
function isValidType(value) {
    return lang_1.isPresent(value) && (value instanceof lang_1.Type);
}
```

Essentially it is was missing lang_1. The exception message has complaining of about "class0" and "class1".

If I move the exact same code from the iframe to the main window, it works. Also, If I hack the Angular2's isValidType() function to simply return true as follows it also works:

```
function isValidType(value) {
    return true;
}
```

I tried bringing lang_1 in from the main window to the iframe as well, but that did not help.

Can someone, at least, tell me what is going on here, if not how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: I would not follow that js tutorial. Angular 2 is designed in typescript and I would suggest you to work with typescript.

Try require lang and see if that helps `var lang_1 = require('./src/facade/lang');` or `lib/facades.es5`.
Use chrome, IE may not work.
bump to beta 9 or later.

Comment: I am using Chrome, actually. My concern about adding separate instances of these constructs (such as lang_1) is that they won't work together across separate frames...

Comment: Why didn't' you try to add all scripts in the iframe? I guess this is the only way this would work propertly. ("I didn't even try to load Angular2 in that iframe, assuming that would not work.")

Comment: Well, for one, its selectors work on the document in the same "window" as the script by default and I don't know how to tell it to look elsewhere...